# Getting Error code 0x858C001B while trying to install Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need help please.
Our SQL server VMs have just been migrated from one domain to a different domain. Migration was by cloning the VMs so SQL Server instances are untouched.

However, in trying to add the Integration Services feature to an instance, using the Installation Centre, we get the error:

[image]

I've done some Googling but not sure yet how to resolve the issue. Any ideas please?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading the install media?

Comment: No, I haven't re-downloaded the install media because I'm not sure what to do if I re-download it? I don't want to re-install the instance? Please advise. Thank you.